# Como determinar el acumulado en SQL

Tags: sql

estoy haciendo la siguiente consulta para sacar un total acumulado.
Hay que tener en cuenta que uso max(entered_on) para poder traerme solo una linea de cada valor de la columna 1.

```
select number,count ,max(entered_on) from presence
where id = '71' and code = 'usa'
group by number,count

5|12|2021-05-13
2|13|2021-04-30
3|13|2021-04-30
4|13|2021-04-30
1|16|2021-04-30
```

Lo que quiero es poder llegar a esto modificado la consulta anterior, que seria el maximo de la columna 1 y la suma de la columna 2:

```
5|67
```

Comment: la suma de la columna dos, es la suma de todos los registros sin importar el grupo?

Comment: Si, es la suma de los registros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberías especificar que base de datos estás utilizando.

Puedes utilizar tu query como una subquery, y seleccionar el mayor valor de la columna "number" y sumar los valores de la columna count.

```
SELECT MAX(number) AS max_number, SUM(count) AS total_count
FROM (SELECT number, count, max(entered_on) 
      FROM presence
      WHERE id = '71' AND code = 'usa'
      GROUP BY number, count) AS subquery;
```

Comment: El problema es este caso es que cuando uso el sum(count) me termina sumando todas las fechas que tienen ese 'number', y yo quiero que me sume al ultima de cada 'number'

Comment: Bien, ahí modifiqué la query. Utilizo tu query como subquery y selecciono el mayor valor de la columna "number" y sumo la columna "count". Cuando preguntes es importante que compartas la estructura de datos (CREATE TABLE) y datos de ejemplo para poder probar la query.